# file_get_contents está gerando o erro: "Too many open files"

Tags: php, linux, file-get-contents

Eu tenho um script rodando no meu servidor através do [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Esse script faz uma consulta no banco pesquisando por processamentos de solicitações pendentes e, quando encontra, envia os dados de cada solicitação para um endpoint de um webservice de um cliente.

Para cada solicitação, utilizo o `file_get_contents` para abrir um arquivo, porque preciso enviar os dados da imagem através do `base_64_encode`.

Eu gero um log de erro caso o processamento dê alguma falha. Tenho recebido o seguinte erro, referente ao `file_get_contents`

> Failed to open stream: Too many open files

Eu não entendi muito bem o porque desse erro, já que cada solicitação é processada de uma a uma. E assim, teoricamente, o `file_get_contents`, após ler o conteúdo do arquivo, fecha-o logo em seguida.

Então, porque esse erro ocorre? Como posso resolver isso?

*Nota*: Estou usando o Ubuntu 14  e, conforme pesquisei sobre o erro, parece se trata de uma configuração no Linux, mas não entendi muito bem isso.

Comment: Não seria porque o conteúdo do arquivo estourou o buffer?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert li aqui que tá relacionado a um tal de `ulimit`...

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert boa ideia, ao invés de abrir tudo de uma vez com `file_get_contents`, poderia ser uma boa usar `fopen` e ir carregando com o `fread`... Vou ter que mudar a lógica, talvez

Answer (score 2):

Isso pode ser uma limitação no servidor onde o código está sendo executado. Todo o sistema operacional só permite um certo número de arquivos / identificadores / soquetes abertos. Esse limite geralmente é mais reduzido quando o servidor é virtualizado. Em um servidor `Linux`, você pode verificar o limite atual com `ulimit -n` dentro das configurações do servidor, se você tiver acesso root, você pode aumentá-lo com o mesmo comando. Caso contrário, não há muito o que você pode fazer sobre isso (exceto pedir ao seu administrador de hospedagem para aumentá-lo).

Se tiver acesso ao root do servidor, considere fazer essas mudanças nos `confs` do **Linux**, em todo caso, claro que vai ter que ter uma noção básica de **Linux** pra fazer as alterações.

Note que existem dois tipos de limites:

Limites **soft** são simplesmente os limites atualmente aplicados.

Limites **hard** marcam o valor máximo que não pode ser excedido, definindo um limite **soft**

```
In /etc/security/limits.conf // Arquivo que deve procurar para alterar
  soft nofile 1024 
  hard nofile 65535 
Increase ulimit by "ulimit -n 65535" 
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max 
In /etc/sysctl.conf   // Arquivo que deve procurar para alterar
  fs.file-max=65535
```

> Links Úteis;
>
> [How to set ulimit values](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334)
>
> [How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux)
>
> [How to Increase Number of Open Files Limit in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-set-open-file-limits-in-linux/)